# Server/Client Connection (Python)

Tags: python, networking

This is my code for server :

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "192.168.1.3"
port = 8000
print (host)
print (port)
serversocket.bind((host, port))

serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server started and listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("connection found!")
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print (data)
    clientsocket.send("data is sent".encode())
```

and for Client :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host ="59.93.199.XXX"
port =8000
s.connect((host,port))
s.send('randomData'.encode())
data = ''
data = s.recv(1024).decode()
print (data)
s.close
```

I want this to work across two computers across the internet. 
when I put host="192.168.1.3" in client, it works fine, but that's only for computers connected to the same network. 
The thing is, that while server is running, and i check for open port online,the server shows 'connection found', but it does not connect to server via client. 
what am i doing wrong ?
PORT 8000 is open.

192.168.1.3 is my computer's IP and 192.168.1.1 is the gateway
ERROR THAT I GET WHEN I RUN CLIENT :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Harsh's\Desktop\aaa.py", line 6, in 
>       s.connect((host,port)) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> across two computers across the internet

In this case, your server either needs a public, static address, or you have to configure your router to route incoming connections for port 8000 to be redirected (translated) to your server (NATting, PATting, etc).

Whose address is "59.93.199.XXX"? Your router's? Then there you need to do the translating/redirecting/chaining.

After some tests, the problem showed to be:

```
s = socket.socket()
```

instead of

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: it IS directed . 
www.yourgetsignal.com shows its open. 
i have dyanamic ip, but without resetting, why doesn't it work ?

Comment: In this case, bind your server to its public address, not to its local. Or bind it to all available interfaces.

Comment: i am a noob, please explain more elaborately
if i make host =<myIP> in server, it shows errors. 
i think the server is okay, coz it shows connected messages when i check for open port. 
i think the problem is with the client side

Comment: Try using `host = ''` (all interfaces) in your server script.

Comment: I am not much into Windows, but 10061 sounds like your router is translating the port, but on the destination machine no matching service is running.

Comment: Actually this problem apparently has nothing to do with python. And without your complete network configuraion of your LAN, your router, your routes, your NAT, your PAT, etc, any attempt at answering will be  like poking with a stick in a muddy puddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45566/discussion-between-user2670775-and-hyperboreus)